# Typographic conventions for width of figures in LaTeX data analysis reports

Tags: presentation

I've been thinking recently about conventions for figure width in data analysis reports that lead to PDFs (e.g., in A4 or Letter size). My usual context is R, Sweave, and LaTeX.

The default figure width in Sweave is 80% of the text-width (i.e., the width of a paragraph of text).

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.80\textwidth}
```

**Questions:**

- Is it reasonable for the width of figures to be wider than the text-width (i.e., to spill into the margins)?
- Is the 80% rule of text-width a good one or would, for example 100%, or some other value be better?
- Should the figure widths be consistent throughout a document (or perhaps with two sizes for small and large figures) or should the width be adapted completely to the content?

Any references or thoughts on best practice in this regards would be most welcome.

Comment: This question seems to me to be straying beyond the bounds of this site. Not only is it subjective, it seems to me a question of page layout graphic design rather than statistics or data visualisation. While the design of figures displaying quantitative information is certainly within our bounds, I'd say the placement and sizing of such figures is straying outside.

Comment: Try on tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Okay. I've posted the question on Tex.SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5351/aesthetically-pleasing-width-for-figures-in-latex-documents

Comment: @onestop I changed the title to try to make it less subjective

Comment: I was more worried about the subject matter than the subjectivity to be honest. How about proposing it as a suitable question for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design ?

Comment: @onestop I can see where you are coming from. I can see how general graphic design, and tex sites are relevant. However, I have a specific interest in what other users of Sweave and R do, and how they justify their decisions. Thus, I thought I'd get more relevant answers here. Perhaps this is an issue other users of Sweave and R encounter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll second @onestop comment about the fact that this question seems marginally related to statistical analysis or reporting.

That being said, I can't refrain from thinking of Ed. Tufte's work on the display of quantitative information, especially the design of his books which mixes different graphics layouts: some figures or tables are put in the margin, other in the body with caption in the margin, and large figures may extend beyond the body (full page width). The [tufte-latex](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) project offers $\LaTeX$ classes for articles/handouts and books in the spirit of Ed. Tufte's design. Some examples are included on the project page; I particularly like the [example handout](http://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/files/sample-handout-3.5.0.pdf).
On a related point, I also like the [tutorial](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/opetus/metodi/vegantutor.pdf) from the [vegan](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html) R package.

My personal approach is to use 80% or 100% of text width (and keep it consistent across all the document), but I often play with the `width`, `height`, and `cex` arguments of `pdf()` when exporting figure so as to get the most clean and readable figure. It also happens to me to rely on a different layout--figure 60% and caption 40%, side by side, 100% of text width--for small illustrations or graphics.